# Generated app of sencha does not have touch folder

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

"sencha generate app MyApp MyApp" is completing without any error . But Certain folders are missing in the generated app. My MyApp directory has

sencha,
app,
resources

but folders like,

build,
packages,
touch

have not been generated.. What could've gone wrong..? It used to work well till a few days back.. Please help..

Comment: Did you update the SDK without updating the Cmd or the other way round?

Comment: No. i didn't update anything. I didn't use it for a week or so. When i typed that command, it's not working now..! I tried deleting the whole touch-2.3.0 folder and unzipped again.. Still no hope..

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you didn't switch into the Sencha SDK folder to create your project.

You can either create your project from another directory like this:

```
sencha -sdk /path/to/sdk generate app MyApp /path/to/MyApp
```

Or you switch into the SDK path and do it like that:

```
cd /path/to/SDK
sencha generate app MyApp /path/to/MyApp
```

Hope that helps?

Comment: I'm switching into the SDK path and running that command. It used to work fine. But now it isn't. "Sencha" command is working properly. App is also generating . but "touch", "build" and "package" folders are not being generated in the app.

Comment: It isn't that bad if 'build' and 'package' are not there. 'Build' will be created if you build the app and as 'package' is empty anyway you can add this folder on your own if you need it. Have you tried moving your SDK to another path and trying it again?

Comment: Yes. I have tried moving the path. Still no use. What you have said is true, "package" and "build" are not that mush necessary at present. But "touch" is important right. Without that my app is not running.